# Sum and difference beetwen hours in Java (over 24h)

Tags: android, time, date-arithmetic

I'm developing an Android App and I need to calculate some times (with Joda libs).
I would like to know if exist a Java class who does this.

The cases that I would like to calculate (in example):

Case 1:

```
t1 = "13:40"
t2 = "12:30"
result = t1 + t2 --> 26:10
```

Case 2:

```
t1 = "13:40"
t2 = "12:30"
result = t1 - t2 --> 1:10
```

Case 2.1:

```
t1 = "13:40"
t2 = "14:00"
result = t1 - t2 --> -0:20
```

Thanks!! :)

Comment: Yes, but I need to calculate the worked hours in a week. For example, if I work 8 hours per 5 days, the result must be 40:00 hours...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following JodaTime-code handles both inputs and result as temporal amounts, not points in time:

**CASE 1:**

```
PeriodFormatterBuilder builder = new PeriodFormatterBuilder();
builder.minimumPrintedDigits(2);
builder.printZeroAlways();
builder.appendHours();
builder.appendLiteral(":");
builder.appendMinutes();
PeriodFormatter pf = builder.toFormatter();

Period period1 = pf.parsePeriod("13:40");
Period period2 = pf.parsePeriod("12:30");
Period total = period1.plus(period2);
Period normalized = total.normalizedStandard(PeriodType.time());

System.out.println("TOTAL PERIOD: " + total); // PT25H70M
System.out.println("NORMALIZED PERIOD: " + normalized); // PT26H10M
System.out.println("FORMATTED NORMALIZED PERIOD: " + pf.print(normalized)); // 26:10
```

**CASE 2 + 2.1:**

```
PeriodFormatterBuilder builder = new PeriodFormatterBuilder();
builder.minimumPrintedDigits(2);
builder.printZeroAlways();
builder.appendHours();
builder.appendLiteral(":");
builder.appendMinutes();
PeriodFormatter pf = builder.toFormatter();

Period period1 = pf.parsePeriod("13:40");
Period period2 = pf.parsePeriod("14:00");

boolean negative = false;

if (period1.toStandardDuration().isShorterThan(period2.toStandardDuration())) {
  Period tmp = period1;
  period1 = period2;
  period2 = tmp;
  negative = true;
}

Period total = period1.minus(period2);
Period normalized = total.normalizedStandard(PeriodType.time());
System.out.println("NORMALIZED PERIOD: " + (negative ? "-" : "") + normalized);
System.out.println(
  "FORMATTED NORMALIZED PERIOD: " + (negative ? "-" : "") + pf.print(normalized)
); // -00:20
```

Note that due to insufficient sign handling of JodaTime (which likes to print the sign not in front but midth inside period expression) some clunky workaround is necessary.

Comment: wow, splendid!!! :) I'm not at home to try your code now, but I think that is a fantastic solution for me!! :) I reply when I will try your code...thank you man!! You are awesome! :))

Comment: Excuse me, I have a last question: the Period class allows negative times? For example: 
period1 = "3:00" 
period1 = "-4:00" 
result_sum = "-1:00"

Need I to do a workaround? Thanks! :)

Comment: @user3449772 Yes, JodaTime knows negative periods. The definition of sign in Joda-periods is annoying because JodaTime associates a sign with every single period field, not with the whole period. For example you can get mixed signs like PT-3H20M (fake ISO-8601-notation). Therefore my workaround for sign handling given in code.

Answer (score 1):

I calculate here 05:00:00 PM this format you can take any format which you want:

```
    String string1 = "05:00:00 PM";
    Date time1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss aa").parse(string1);
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.setTime(time1);

    String string2 = "09:00:00 AM";
    Date time2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss aa").parse(string2);
    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar2.setTime(time2);
    calendar2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    Date x = calendar1.getTime();
    Date xy = calendar2.getTime();
    long diff = x.getTime() - xy.getTime();
    diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
    float diffHours = diffMinutes / 60;
    System.out.println("diff hours" + diffHours);
```

Comment: Thanks! You're awesome and I appreciated your solution! But I think that the solution proposed by Meno Hochschild was better for me! :) Thank you man for reply!